# How can I make pushd autocomplete CDPATH entries?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have [bash-completion](https://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) installed, and I get a lot of mileage out of tab-completing CDPATH entries when using `cd`. I'd like to get the same functionality from `pushd`. I started diving into the bash-completion source code, but I'm a little out of my depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your .bash_profile:

```
# Taken from /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion on my
# Ubuntu 16.04 system, substituting "pushd" for "cd":
if shopt -q cdable_vars; then
    complete -v -F _cd -o nospace pushd
else
    complete -F _cd -o nospace pushd
fi
```

Works for me. Note that it's indented, as it's "protected" by an `if [ -n "$PS1" ]`, to ensure it doesn't run for a non-interactive session. (My `.bashrc` run `.bash_profile` to handle some ways that shells are started, such as via `ESC-x shell` in GNU Emacs, which reads only `.bashrc`.)

Comment: It looks like, since I originally posted, the bash-completion scripts have been updated and include this out of the box.